# Type binding redirect in C#

Tags: c#

My question towards class(or type) level binding redirect, not about assembly binding redirect.
For ex, i have C# class called Class1 in DLL1.DLL, can the requests for this class be redirected to Class1 in DLL2.DLL?

Thanks for your help
Bhava

Comment: How are you referencing the classes?  Are you referencing them dynamically with reflection or in static source code?  What is the reason you need to do this (there may be a different way to solve your problem)?

Comment: your question is not clear?

Comment: Yes, it is static binding. Reason is, we are migrating some of the libraries from old environment(with old libraries) to new environment(with new libraries). And it happened that both old libraries and new libraries happened to have same classes.
A host program is referencing these old libraries which are no more used, so whenever there is request for old libraries, needed to redirect to new libraries. 
Hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking to redirect a method from class A of assembly 1 to another method of class B of assembly 2, then it is not possible.

If you have two assemblies with different versions, just specify the redirect in config : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please don't use "answer" as comment field (see [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment), search there for similar posts if one does not cover it). I've removed unrelated text as you've actually provided possible answer (which is the right thing to put in "Answer" unlike "new here" text)

Comment: "If you are asking to redirect a method from class A of assembly 1 to another method of class B of assembly 2, then it is not possible."

Yes, thanks for the reply.